# preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2 to be a valid callback

Tags: php

I'm learning PHP with some pre-made websites so I can see how it's done because I'm a visual learner, but I've run into a problem.

I got an error saying

> preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead

Now I know this happens because of a newer PHP that doesn't support `preg_replace()` but `preg_replace_callback()`, but upon changing it, I get this error:

> preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2, 'preg_replace('/(.{59})/', '\$1< >', '$1')', to be a valid callback

The code makes too long messages in a chatbox divided into two separate ones to keep all letters inside the chat window.

The error was located in line 20, where only the `$msg);` stands.

```
if ($shoutbox['fixLongWords'] > 5 && $shoutbox['fixLongWords'] < $shoutbox['maxMsgLenght'])
{
    $non_breaking_space = $context['utf8'] ? ($context['server']['complex_preg_chars'] ? '\x{A0}' : "\xC2\xA0") : '\xA0';

    if ($context['browser']['is_gecko'] || $context['browser']['is_konqueror'])
        $breaker = '<span style="margin:0 -0.5ex 0 0"> </span>';
    elseif ($context['browser']['is_opera'])
        $breaker = '<span style="margin:0 -0.65ex 0 -1px"> </span>';
    else
        $breaker = '<span style="width:0;margin:0 -0.6ex 0 -1px"> </span>';

    $shoutbox['fixLongWords'] = (int) min(1024, $shoutbox['fixLongWords']);

    if (strlen($msg) > $shoutbox['fixLongWords'])
    {
        $msg = strtr($msg, array($breaker => '< >', '&nbsp;' => $context['utf8'] ? "\xC2\xA0" : "\xA0"));
        $msg = preg_replace(
            '~(?<=[>;:!? ' . $non_breaking_space . '\]()]|^)([\w\.]{' . $shoutbox['fixLongWords'] . ',})~e' . ($context['utf8'] ? 'u' : ''),
            'preg_replace(\'/(.{' . ($shoutbox['fixLongWords'] - 1) . '})/' . ($context['utf8'] ? 'u' : '') . '\', \'\\$1< >\', \'$1\')',
            $msg);
        $msg = strtr($msg, array('< >' => $breaker, $context['utf8'] ? "\xC2\xA0" : "\xA0" => '&nbsp;'));
    }
}
```

Anyone have any idea what might be causing the problem?

Comment: The second argument of `preg_replace_callback()` is either an anonymous function e.g. `function(){...}` or a function name e.g. `"functionNameAsString"`, which you then define like a normal function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP documentation [describes this function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) as

> Perform a regular expression search and replace using a callback:
>
> ```
> mixed preg_replace_callback ( mixed $pattern , callable $callback , mixed $subject [, int $limit = -1 [, int &$count ]] )
> ```

The `callable` class requires the name of a function (as a string, e.g. `'print_r'`) or an actual function `function(){ // do something }`.

The `preg_replace_callback()` process will pass an array of matches into the "callable function" and return a string. From the docs, describing the second parameter:

> A callback that will be called and passed an array of matched elements in the subject string. The callback should return the replacement string. This is the callback signature:
>
> ```
> string handler ( array $matches )
> ```

Comment: I see. Thanks for explaining this, tho I've just noticed that I have a newer PHP version on my home computer and not on the school server, so I'll leave it be until the school updates and if the problem comes back I'll be asking the teacher. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: If I may ask, what are the two versions?